# is there any way we can mask the value entering into jText area at runtime and should clear the contents if backspace kept pressed

Tags: java, swing, textarea, keylistener

I have a requirement where need to mask the value entering into jText area at runtime. I am able to achieve this but problem is scenario with backspace. When I press back space sequentially (one by one) then it work while if I kept pressing then its counting the event as one and removing only one character (by considering the key event as one key released).

Here my code snippets is :

```
public void showPrompt() throws InterruptedException {
        sem.acquire();
        this.toFront();
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
        if(encryptKeystroke == true) {
            jTextArea.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                }

                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                }

                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

                    if (e.getExtendedKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
                        text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);
                    }
                    else {
                        text += String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar());
                    }
                    jTextArea.setText(text.replaceAll(".", "*"));
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Is there any way if I kept pressing the backspace then it should remove all the characters irrespective of considering it one key event ?

Comment: Have you though about using a [JPasswordField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) ?

Comment: What does your code do if someone pastes text with Ctrl-V or ⌘V?  What if the user selects all of the text and then presses backspace?  (This is why you should use a JPasswordField instead of trying to implement this yourself.  This functionality is more complicated than you’ve assumed.)

Comment: A KeyListener should not be used for this sort of thing.

Comment: I am not supposed to use JPassword. and here in actually i just need to mask with any character (don't have the requirement exactly like password)

Answer (score 0):

As you have said in the comment that the requirements are not exactly like the password and so you won't be using JPasswordField, I would like to give a solution for the question.

Here, the code to detect a backspace key stroke is written inside the keyReleased() method. Now, the keyReleased() method will be called by the keyListener when you will pull your finger up from a key in this case your backspace key. That is why even if you continuously keep pressing the backspace key, it will execute the code only once i.e. only when you release the key.

Now, you wish to remove one character every time backspace is **pressed** so you can just move your code from the keyReleased() method to the keyPressed() method.

If you move the code inside the keyPressed() method, then the code will be executed at every key stroke even if you continuously keep pressing the backspace key.